# testing remote IP address behaviors on a Node Express server

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, jasmine-node

I'm writing unit tests for a Node.js Express server. The server does some stuff that depends on the remote client's IP address, retrieved using [`req.ip`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.ip) on the server.

How can I write unit tests that will spoof their own IP addresses to test the server's responses, or is there a better way to achieve the same end? (I'm writing the unit tests in jasmine-node, if it matters.)

Comment: what do you mean with "their own IP addresses"?

Comment: I mean each unit test can pretend to send requests from a different IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the trust proxy feature of express to fake requests from ip addresses for your tests. When you enable trust proxy in express by `app.enable('trust proxy')`
 you can add the `X-Forwarded-For`HTTP header and set it's value to the ip required by the test.

The express ip/trust proxy behavior is documented [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.ip)

Comment: Is that a behavior I generally want to enable on my server?

Comment: If you have a proxy before your express app, yes. Otherwise definitely no because clients could spoof an ip address by setting the X-Forwarded-For header

Comment: Hmm, I'd really like a solution that doesn't make my server vulnerable. I'm just using IP addresses as a fallback way to do localization, but still. I suppose I could send a testing IP in a made-up HTTP header that a hacker is unlikely to stumble upon, and it really won't harm anything if it is spoofed, but that's super-ugly...

Comment: For writing tests this behavior is ok, because you want to fake IPs. For a production system turn it off of course.

Comment: Yes, that's one option, but I was hoping to test the production code and not have to remember to modify it. :)